# Trying to insert some data with a fallback, using ContentAreaByName

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to pull in some content from 'my contents', but am having trouble.

This is what I'm currently using, and it seems to work as long as I always specify 'OFFER12':

```
%%[
Var @promo
set @promo = ContentAreaByName(concat("my contents\Responsive\",   Format(DateAdd(InputDate, "1","M"), "MMMM yyyy"), '\',OFFER12))
]%%
%%=v(@promo)=%%
```

What I'm trying to do, is specify a default file to load if 'OFFER12' is empty. This is what I have so far:

```
%%[Var @promo]%%
%%[IF not empty(OFFER12) THEN
set @promo = ContentAreaByName(concat("my contents\resp\",  Format(DateAdd(InputDate, "1","M"), "MMMM yyyy"), '\',OFFER12)) ELSE
set @promo = ContentAreaByName(concat("my contents\resp\",     Format(DateAdd(InputDate, "1","M"), "MMMM yyyy"), '\default')) ]%%
%%=v(@promo)=%%
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `END-IF`

```
%%[ 
Var @promo 
IF not empty(OFFER12) THEN
  set @promo = ContentAreaByName(concat("my contents\resp\", Format(DateAdd(InputDate, "1","M"), "MMMM yyyy"),'\',OFFER12))
ELSE   
  set @promo = ContentAreaByName(concat("my contents\resp\",    Format(DateAdd(InputDate, "1","M"), "MMMM yyyy"), '\default'))  
END-IF 
]%%
%%=v(@promo)=%%
```

You could also write it like this:

```
%%[
var @offer, @promo
set @offer = iif(empty(OFFER12),"default","OFFER12")
set @promo = ContentAreaByName(concat("my contents\resp\", Format(DateAdd(InputDate, "1","M"), "MMMM yyyy"),'\',@offer))
]%%
%%=v(@promo)=%%
```